# What was the need for defining kinematic viscosity?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, definition, flow, viscosity

How is kinematic viscosity physically different than dynamic viscosity? What was the need for defining a new quantity ie kinematic viscosity though one can get one from the other? Do try to give a detailed answer wherein the motivation for defining is clearly evident.

Comment: Like other combination parameters, it appears frequently in many situations at the combination.  For example, in transient flow problems, such as start up of lateral  movement of a flat plate, in which a fluid is in the gap between two parallel planes.

Comment: @Chet Miller once read somewhere that kinematic viscosity is used for analysis where forces are not considered would you kindly elaborate this by giving a specific concrete example?

Comment: Sorry.  I don't care about generalizing it like this.  If it comes up in a specific problem, I work with it then.